# C# System.Windows.Forms.Control.TagプロパティをASP.NETでも使いたい。

Tags: c#, asp.net

ウィンドウズフォームのコントロールであるSystem.Windows.Forms.Controlには
Tagプロパティというのがあり、好きなデータを突っ込んで便利に使えるようです。
しかしASPのSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControlにはTagプロパティはないようです。
ASPでもTagを使いたいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか。

いまのところ解決策として各コントロールクラスを継承してTagプロパティを追加した
新しいクラスを作って使っていますがもっと良い解決策はないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebControl`には拡張属性を設定する領域として[`Attributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes(v=vs.100).aspx)プロパティが定義されています。

たとえば`data-tag`属性を使用する場合、`.aspx`側は以下のようになります。

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" data-tag="1" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" data-tag="2" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" data-tag="3" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" data-tag="4" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" data-tag="5" />
</div>
</form>
```

コードビハインドでは`Attributes`のインデクサーから値が取得/設定できます。

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var b = (Button)sender;
    var i = int.Parse(b.Attributes["data-tag"]);
    b.Attributes["data-tag"] = b.Text = (i * 2).ToString();
}
```

ただ本来はHTML属性を設定する場所ですので、副作用として出力結果に`data-tag`属性が追加されることになります。もしユーザーに絶対知られたくない値を指定したいのであれば、セッションを利用すると複数同時リクエストの対応が難しいので`Page.ViewState`にJSONなどで保存しておくのが良いと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。sayuriさんにはセッションを薦められていますが
pgrhoさんはユーザーに情報を知られたくないなら複数同時リクエストの対応に難があるとおっしゃる。
セッションを使うと具体的にどのような問題が発生するのでしょうか。

Comment: @Jogenara まずセッションはWebアプリケーション全体で共通の値ですので、`UniqueID`等では異なるページ間での重複が発生しえます。これはキーにページの完全修飾名などを含めれば回避できますが、ユーザーが同一のページを同時に開いている場合は単純な方法では回避できません。あと明示的に削除することが難しいのでセッションサーバーの容量を浪費します。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Attributesが思っていたものに近いので使わせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

まずWebFormsはブラウザーからのリクエストの度に毎回オブジェクトが生成し直されます。そのため、WinFormsのようにオブジェクトを維持することはできないため`Tag`プロパティが用意されていません。

ブラウザーからのリクエスト間で状態を保持する機能としていくつかの[サーバー側の状態管理オプション](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/z1hkazw7(v=vs.100).aspx#%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E5%81%B4%E3%81%AE%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E3%82%AA%E3%83%97%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)が用意されています。無難なものとしては**セッション状態**（session state）です。
WebFormsからは`HttpContext.Current.Session`でアクセスできます。（[セッション状態から値を読み取る](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/03sekbw5(v=vs.110).aspx)、[セッション状態の値を保存する](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/6ad7zeeb(v=vs.100).aspx)）

> いまのところ解決策として各コントロールクラスを継承してTagプロパティを追加した
>   新しいクラスを作って使っています

継承するくらいなら後付けで機能追加可能な拡張メソッドをお勧めします。`Tag`プロパティは作成できませんが、`GetTag()`拡張メソッドと`SetTag()`拡張メソッドを用意してはどうでしょうか？

```
public static class TagExtensions {
    public static object GetTag(this Control self) {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[self.UniqueID];
    }
    public static void SetTag(this Control self, object value) {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[self.UniqueID] = value;
    }
}
```

例として`UniqueID`プロパティを使用しましたが、適宜変更してください。